# SQL query with the condition of equality with the value of the drop down list

Tags: sql, ms-access, conditional-statements, where-clause

I work in MS Access with the query in sql. 
I have table where in one of the fields is drop down list connected to the multiple values from other tables (multiple values are shown in list as well). How is it possible to set condition of checking equality with the values in the DD list in the WHERE clause in SQL?

[image: field with dd list]

SQL code

```
SELECT H.Hoiuruumi_kood, H.Nimetus, H.Hind, H.Hoiuruumi_aadress, HS.Nimetus AS Hoiuruumi_suurus, HSL.Nimetus AS Hoiuruumi_hetkeseisund
FROM Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liik AS HSL
INNER JOIN (Hoiuruumi_suurus AS HS
INNER JOIN Hoiuruum AS H ON HS.Hoiuruumi_suuruse_kood = H.Hoiuruumi_suuruse_kood) ON HSL.Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liiki_kood = H.Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liiki_kood
WHERE H.Hoiuruumi_seidundi_liiki_kood = 'HSL-01';
```

Comment: Could you give us some example?

Comment: I added some pictures

Comment: Thanks, but could you provide text format instead of images? You can 
 let value of ddl be a parameter pass into SQL @lisa

Comment: ok, I also added SQL code @D-Shih

Comment: Please post the query of that drop down by going into design mode of table, locate the specific field, and click second tab at bottom of field properties and post the Row Source Query of combobox.

Comment: @Parfait `SELECT [Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liik].[Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liiki_kood], [Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liik].[Nimetus] FROM Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liik `

Comment: What values do you need from drop down as there are two columns? Please edit your post showing a sampe of your current results and then desired results.

Comment: @Parfait I can't show my current results because it can't find a second  parameter here `HSL.Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liiki_kood = H.Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liiki_kood` , but I want it to show me results only if the value in field "Hoiuruumi_seisundi_liiki_kood" is HSL-01 or HSL-02

Comment: Why not use `IN()` or `OR` clauses?: `WHERE H.Hoiuruumi_seidundi_liiki_kood IN ('HSL-01', 'HSL-02');`

Comment: Its worth mentioning that when you have combobox values within a table, the way to "check their value" is often done by "index order" or the values in the combobox, and not their "actual value." I actually really hate when tables are designed this way, not that there is anything wrong  with per say, i just wish that people would stop doing it all together.